# 3D модель с активной камерой

Tags: java, android, 3d

Подскажите движок или библиотеку, позволяющую загрузить 3D модель `.obj` и имеющий возможность перемещаться по загруженой 3D модели. Допустим, существует 3D модель стола 1к1 в натуральную величину, и я взяв в руки телефон, обошел бы его и посмотрел со всех сторон.

Comment: А ручками? Обж достаточно простой формат.